# Associated Bundles: Necessity of Action on Left and Right?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

In the construction of the bundle associated to some (right, say) $G$-principal bundle $P\to B$ and (left, say) action $G$ on a space $F$, we construct a bundle with typical fiber $F$ as the orbit space $P\times F/G$ where $G$ acts on $P\times F$ by $g\cdot(x,f)=(xg^{-1},gf)$.

**Q1.** Topologically, is it really required for $P$ to be a right $G$-principal bundle, as opposed to a left? It appears to me that everything works out with $g\cdot(x,f)=(gx,gf)$. We could also simply define a left action in a compatible manner in the usual way: $gx\mathop{=}\limits^{\scriptstyle\scriptstyle{\mathrm{def}}}xg^{-1}$.

**Q2.** If it is not strictly necessary from a topological standpoint, what motivates this definition?

(Probably silly questions, I know!)

Comment: You can find an answer at [MathOverflow: Why does the group act on the right on the principal bundle?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/50473/why-does-the-group-act-on-the-right-on-the-principal-bundle). I like the answer by @Jeffrey Giansiracusa using Borel construction.

Comment: Hi @ChoF, thanks for the link! Unfortunately, my question is more low-brow, I fear. I mean to ask why we require $P$ to be a right (resp. left) $G$-prinicipal bundle and $F$ to be a left (resp. right) $G$-space.

Comment: One reason would be the aesthetically pleasing identity $[xg,f] =[ x, gf]$.